Finding Local Python Modules Pylint VSCode
I have a project like this:
.
├── container1
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── module1.py
│   └── venv1
│       ├── bin
│       ├── include
│       ├── lib
│       └── pyvenv.cfg
├── container2
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── module2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── module2.py
│   └── venv2
│       ├── bin
│       ├── include
│       ├── lib
│       └── pyvenv.cfg
└── project.code-workspace

It's a docker project with two containers, and for development I've got virtual environments in each container folder.
I've set the interpreter for the corresponding virtual environment for each container folder. However, in VSCode pylint can't resolve the local python modules e.g. module1.
